# Open task in grunt-contrib-connect specifying the browser mode and document mode in appName parameter

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using nodeJS to automate my javascript web app developement, and I always has to ensure the app works fine in all browsers including IE >=8 , now I have IE10 installed on my laptopn ,and I am using `grunt-contrib-connect` package to open the app in multiple browsers using the connect task like this

```js
connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          keepalive: true,
          port: 3001,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          base: '.',
          index: 'fab_1-3.app.htm',
          open: {
              target: 'http://localhost:3001/fab_1-3.app.htm',
              appName: 'iexplore'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now , what I want is it to open in IE specifying the document mode and browser mode as well(using nodeJS/grunt) , is it possible to do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Install the [windows module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343579/111372) via npm
- Set the document mode via one of the following registry keys:

  - [FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106228/1113772)
  - [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730#browser_emulation)
- Set the browser mode via [JsRoboKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685768/1113772)